# Ruby On Rails...What do partials have access do (Locals, instance variables...anything?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the code snippet below, it appears that the form_user_fields partial does not have access to either patient_form or user_fields, but it does have access to @patient. Is this the expected behavior?

```
<%= form_for @patient do |patient_form| %>
    <%= patient_form.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>

        <% render :partial => 'shared/form_user_fields' %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, partials have access to the same variables as other views(instance variables from the controller.)  They won't have access to variables that you create in other views that include the partials, that is the expected behavior.

If you want access to your local variables, you can pass them to the partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/form_user_field", :locals => {:user_fields => user_fields, :patient_form => patient_form} %>
```

Comment: What if the partial being referenced is in another controller? Or if it happens to be in the root of /views? Are there any variables or must they all be passed as params?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the partial is (in your example, you're using a shared one). The partial will still only have access to the instance variables set during the current request/action, and you'll have to pass any other local variables (except for local variables that are defined **inside** the partial, of course).